# jquery instead of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = document.getElementById("tab");
        table.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
        var rows = table.rows;
        
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         if(i % 2 == 0) {
          rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
         }
        }
       });
```

```html
<html>
       
       <head>
      <title>JJJJS</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       
       <body>
      <table id="tab">
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     
       
       
       </body>
    </html>
```

It is working, but how can I achieve similar result using only jQuery? I was trying to use something like `$("#tab");` but it isn't working for me. Where I make mistake? I mean I want to color i % 2 == 0 rows.

@edit:

for example it not working

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $("#tab");
                table.css("border-collapse", "collapse");
                var rows = table.rows;

                for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if(i % 2 == 0) {
                        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: "but it isn't working for me" What exactly is not working?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: (It got it backward, but it's the same answer: Try to do it, and then if you get stuck, post a question about what you're stuck on.)

Comment: `#tab { border-collapse: collapse } #tab tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: red }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0;
  $('#tab tr').each(function() {
     if(!(i++%2)) { // if(i % 2 == 0 and increment i as well
       $(this).css('background','red');
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
       
       <head>
      <title>JJJJS</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       
       <body>
      <table id="tab">
       <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     
       
       
       </body>
    </html>
```